# Vector Fields and Line Integrals

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

I wanted to know that in order to calculate the Line Integral of a Vector Field, is it necessary that the Vector Field has to be a Conservative Vector Field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If a vector field is conservative it simplifies matters by applying the fundamental theorem of line integrals (which is the fundamental theorem of calculus in disguise), but it is **not** necessary.